# Django rest: Invalid choice error

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have model with char field with choices and serializer with same choices. But when I try save object - I get invalid _choice error "Select a valid choice. ... is not one of the available choices"

```
AUDIENCE_CHOICES = (
    ('m', 'me'),
    ('f', 'friends'),
    ('e', 'everyone'),
)

class Challenge(models.Model):
    audience = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=AUDIENCE_CHOICES)

class ChallengePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audience = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=AUDIENCE_CHOICES)
```

Why it hepends? What is the right format of choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct choice would in this case be one of `m`, `f` or `e`, not `...`.